# Exponential functions help appreciated!

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How on earth do you work these exponential functions out? Please explain and show exact steps in working. I am very confused as I have no idea where to start or what to do.

a) $5k^2=25k$

b) $4^{2x}-1= 8^x+3$

HINT - first convert $4$ and $8$ into powers of $2$

Comment: Hi!  Pro Tip: surround your math with dollar signs (\$math\$).  It will make it format pretty.

Comment: Your first question requires only simple algebraic manipulations...e.g., *factor*; you're making (a) more difficult than it needs to be.  Why don't you add what you've tried, using the hint, for (b)? At least post the equation resulting from following the hint.

Comment: Ethan, I didn't say that $b)$ was a cinch...only $(a)$ was probably easier than first met the OP's eyes.

Comment: b) Requires solving the quartic equation, $u^4-u^3-4=0$, which doesn't have any rational solutions, sense your having trouble with $a$ I assume you made a mistake in copying down $b$?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

(a) $5k^2=25k\implies 5k(k-5)=0 $

(b) $4^{2x}=(2^2)^{2x}=2^{4x}=(2^x)^4, 8^x=(2^3)^x=(2^x)^3$

$\implies 2^{4x}-2^{3x}-4=0$

If $f(x)= 2^{4x}-2^{3x}-4, f(0)=-4<0, f(1)=4>0\implies $ there is a root in $(0,1)$

As $f(x)$ is increasing function, this will be sole real root

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20y%5E4-y%5E3-4=0) shows that the real roots of $y^4-y^3-4=0$ are around $-1.21$ and $+1.74$ (Putting $2^x=y$), again  for real $x,2^x>0$

So, the only real root will be $2^x\approx1.74\implies x\approx\log_2{1.74}$

Comment: Why are you assuming x is an integer?

Comment: Yes it can,
 take $x\approx .0806038..$

Comment: @Ethan, thanks for your input. Rectified the answer. Btw, how have you identified the root?

Answer (score 1):

$(a)$ $5k^2=25k \iff 5k^2 - 25k = 0 \iff 5k(k - 5) = 0$

$(b)$ $4^{2x}-1= 8^x+3.\;$  Using the hint $$4^{2x} - 8^x = 2^2 \iff  = (2^2)^{2x} - (2^3)^x = 2^2 $$

I'll let you play around with $(b)$ and follow-up (comment below this post) with how far you get...or update your original post.

Comment: I still don't understand a). What exactly are you doing? Why are you getting 5k^2-25k=0?

Comment: A'marie: in a) $5k^2 = 25k \iff 5k^2 - 25k = 25k - 25k = 0$. We want to solve for $x$, so we put want all terms with $x$ on one side of the equation; we can do this by subtracting $25k$ from each side of the equation, giving us, as shown above $5k^2 - 25k=0$. Then we *factor out* $5k$ from each term: recall that by the distribution law, $5k(k - 5) = 5k^2 - 25k = 0$. Now, for what values of $k$ will $5k(k-5) = 0$? When $5k = 0$ or $k - 5 = 0$. Just solve for $k$ in each case: you will have two solutions (two values for $k$ which makes the original equation true.)